# How to simulate k8s node notready

Tags: kubernetes, client-go, kind

I have a project where I need to `handle when a node becomes notready and when it becomes ready`, but I only have one server and I know I can use the **Kind** to create a multi-node cluster, but I don't know how to implement a node that becomes notready and ready

Is there a way to configure certain node `state transitions` for a `Kind-based cluster`? if not, is there another way. I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Shut down a node.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your cluster you should define at least two workernodes and shutdown one.
Or you login to it and stop the container software.

Docker or containerd.

It is not clear out of your question what you are using.